# WinUI 3 - Project Reunion 0.8 (and later Windows App SDK) Deployment Option like 'XCOPY' (?)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop, winui-3

I'm working for an organization that disables our Windows 10 users regular machines all of the following: Microsoft Store, Sideload, and Developer Mode.

I'm developing a new project (on my dev machine, which is less restrictive), that targets those regular restrictive machines.

While I could go with WPF (and XAML Island) for a straightforward EXE XCOPY deployment, I would like to take advantage of 'latest/greatest' innovations like WinUI 3, compiled binding, etc. with .NET 5/WinUI/Windows Apps SDK 1.0.

Is there a walkaround the restriction (Windows Store, Sideload, and Dev Mode disabled) to deploy WinUI3 Desktop app?

Comment: You can just create an unpacked app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app?pivots=winui3-unpackaged-csharp

Comment: To be able to deploy and run your app, you must ensure that the required MSIX packages for the Windows App SDK are installed on the client machine. You can then deploy the app unpackaged.

Answer (score 1):

you have to open your project.csproj and include the Package Type as None

```
    <Project sdk="Microsoft.Net.sdk>
    <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Project>
```

Now go back to VS and instead of project(Package) you can see project (Unpackaged)

Note : install the Windows App SDK runtime and MSIX packages, which are required to run and deploy your app.

Once above is done Goto https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/